# SharePoint 2010 installation - artifacts

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When SharePoint 2010 is installed what all items are copied to the database and what all items are copied to the file system?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically all critical things are stored in Database unless your custom code put something in the file system.

**Database:**

- SharePoint Farm Config (included all settings you can see in central admin)
- Service Application database
- Site Collection database (contentdb)

**File system:**

- SharePoint Server (Assembly, language resources, default stylesheet, _layouts aspx..etc )
- Custom Solutions(WSP - Developed/Deployed by yourself )
- Logs
- Powershell Script